# Syntax C, What does this mean

Tags: c, syntax

Just a short question. I read an example for C Code (I am learning it right now:D ) and there was this written:

*(number++) = a;

number was an unsigned char *number and a an unsigned char.

Perhaps you could help me understand what this *(..++) means. :)
Thank you and have a nice evening!

Comment: Surely you have a list of all the operators in C and what they do...?

Comment: `number` is a pointer; the `number++` means that the pointer will be incremented (to the next element in the array), but the current value will be used.  The `*(…)` dereferences the pointer, assigning the value in `a` (converted if necessary) to the element of the array that `number` pointed to at the start of the statement.  Note that your C textbook should cover this in detail.

Comment: Do you know what a pointer is? If no, that's what you should read about.

Comment: It is, essentially, equivalent to `*number = a; number = number + 1;`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, thats what I needed to know, that the pointer will be incremented. I already know what a pointer is, but sometimes I have problems to understand more complex statements. 

Thank you all for your fast support :D

Comment: It’s also important to understand why the parentheses are there - ie how `*(number++)` differs from `*number++`.  In the latter case, the `*` has higher precedence than the `++`, so `*number++` is the same as `(*number)++`  so gets what `number` is pointing to, then increments and returns that (leaving `number` unchanged)

Comment: @racraman: That's exactly backwards - unary `*` has *lower* precedence than postfix `++`, so `*number++` is parsed as `*(number++)`, not `(*number)++`.  Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators.

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks for the correction, you are quite right - so also proving both that it is never a mistake to use parentheses to clarify ambiguous expressions, and also that it is always a mistake to post before coffee.

Answer (score 1):

It's *roughly* equivalent to writing

```
*number = a;         // write the value in a to what number points to
number = number + 1; // advance number to point to the next object in the sequence
```

`number++` evaluates to the *current* value of number, and as a *side effect* adds 1.  Since `number` is a pointer, adding 1 points it to the next object immediately following whatever `number` points to (not just the next byte).

`*(number++)` dereferences the *result* of `number++`.

I said it's *roughly* equivalent because the order in which `number` and `*number` are updated isn't fixed.  It's possible for it to be evaluated as

```
tmp <- number
number <- number + 1
*tmp <- a
```

or

```
*number <- a
number <- number + 1
```

or even something else.